# react-constructor or componentWillRecevieProps

Tags: reactjs, constructor

i use the react for two month, something the react will do constructor, sometime the react will do componentWillRecevieProps.
eg:

```
renderGroups(){
    return this.props.groups.map( (group, i) => {
        return <PickerGroup key={i} {...group} onChange={this.handleChange} groupIndex={i} defaultIndex={this.state.selected[i]} />;
    });
}
```

this write will do PickGroup constructor every time

Comment: And whats the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its confusing what you are asking here, but you mentioned React will receive a `constructor()` function and sometimes it receives a componentWillReceiveProps.

The purpose of `constructors()` in React is to initialize state. You initialize state when the component is first created. After that, you use state inside the `render()` method and then at some point in the future, you update that state with `setState()`.

Unlike the `constructor()` function, the `render()` method is required for every single React component you create, otherwise, React will throw an error. The `constructor()` function is not required by React, but it is implemented in a class-based component like so:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {

   }

  // React says we have to define render()
  render() {
    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => console.log(position),
      (err) => console.log(err)
    );
    return <div>Latitude: </div>;
  }
};
```

The `constructor()` function is particular to the JavaScript language, not to React.

In a JavaScript class, the `constructor()` function is the first function that is going to be called anytime an instance of this class is created.

Anytime we create a new instance of the `App` component and display it on the screen, this `constructor()` function is going to be automatically and instantly called before anything else.

Now, to get to what I believe is your question, this is not the only way to initialize state in React.

Before I get into the other way to initialize state, you ought to know that when we define the constructor method, it will automatically be called with the `props` object and yes this is the same `props` object you may have seen with functional components and with a class-based component it looks like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {

   }

  // React says we have to define render()
  render() {
    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => console.log(position),
      (err) => console.log(err)
    );
    return <div>Latitude: </div>;
  }
};
```

When you use the `constructor(props)` function, there is one required step which is adding `super(props);`. Why do we have to add this?

Well, remember, I am talking about class-based components here and keep in mind that as a class-based component our `App` component above is extending or borrowing functionality from the `React.Component` base class here.

This base class has a `constructor()` function of its own that has some code inside of it, to setup our react component for us.

When we define a `constructor()` function inside our `App` class, we are essentially, overriding or replacing the `constructor()` function that is inside the `React.Component` class, but we still need to ensure that all the setup code inside of the `React.Component` `constructor()` function still gets called.

So to ensure that the `React.Component`’s `constructor()` function gets called, we call `super(props);`. `super(props)` is a reference to the parents `constructor()` function, that’s all it is.

We have to add `super(props)` every single time we define a `constructor()` function inside a class-based component.

If we don’t we will see an error saying that we have to call `super()`.

The entire reason for defining this `constructor()` function is to initialize our state object.

So in order to initialize my state object, underneath the `super(props);` call I am going to write:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {};
   }

  // React says we have to define render()
  render() {
    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => console.log(position),
      (err) => console.log(err)
    );
    return <div>Latitude: </div>;
  }
};
```

This is our state object that will eventually contain some different pieces of data, some different properties that are very important and relevant to the component being put together.

So lets say I initialized my state with a property called `lat` for latitude because this is a geolocation application I am working on, so now my initialized state looks like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
          super(props);

      this.state = {lat: null};
   }
```

I set the value of the `lat` property to `null` because I don't have a latitude yet and the latitude value will eventually be a number and in such a case when you know the value will be a number that you don't have yet, you can default it to be `null`.

Now, let's say we get an error on this app and we cannot get any data or state at all. We can add another property to state called `errorMessage` and we can default it to be an empty string like so:

```
class App extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
              super(props);

      this.state = {lat: null, errorMessage: '' };
   }
```

Alright, now lets talk about the alternate to the `constructor()`, by changing `this.state` and refactoring to `state = {lat: null, errorMessage: '' };` and then deleting the `constructor()` entirely.

```
class App extends React.Component {
   state = {lat: null, errorMessage: '' };
}
```

This is equivalent to using the `constructor()` function and I can prove this by going to https://babeljs.io/ and adding the above code to the left panel and seeing how Babel translates it into a `constructor()` anyway and it translates it back to `this.state =` like so:
[image]

If you want to reproduce this yourself, please pay attention to what presets have been ticked on the left hand side of Babel tool.

Lastly, you mentioned the alternative to the `constructor()` would be componentWillReceiveProps, but the alternative is actually what I just implemented above.

Please keep in mind the difference between initializing state and utilizing props. Everything described above is initializing state which is what the `constructor()` is for.

In React, you will see different lifecycle methods called, but typically speaking what you will see most of the time is `componentDidMount()` which automatically gets called one time when the component first gets rendered on the screen and you can place logic in there to do initial data loading and other operations you might want to do one time when the component first boots up.

The other lifecycle methods you will typically see most often in addition to `componentDidMount()` is `componentDidUpdate()` and `componentDidUnmount()`, but these are not alternatives to initializing state.

The `constructor()` function is the only lifecycle method used for state initialization, yes, it is a lifecycle method and so is the `render()` method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `Constructor` and `ComponentWillReceiveProps` are used for two different purposes. As per the React DOCS

Constructor:

> The constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted.
>   When implementing the constructor for a React.Component subclass, you
>   should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise,
>   this.props will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to
>   bugs.
>
> The constructor is the right place to initialize state. If you don't
>   initialize state and you don't bind methods, you don't need to
>   implement a constructor for your React component.

componentWillReceiveProps:

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component
>   receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to
>   prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props
>   and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in
>   this method.
>
> Note that React may call this method even if the props have not changed, so make sure to compare the current and next values if you
>   only want to handle changes. This may occur when the parent component
>   causes your component to re-render.
>
> React doesn't call componentWillReceiveProps with initial props during mounting. It only calls this method if some of component's
>   props may update.

So in general you may want to call take actions in your component when the parent component has sent different props, in this case you will use `componentWillReceiveProps` as well as the `constructor` to initialse the state with props.

In your case since your are using a map function you are again and again mounting the same component whenever the `renderGroups` function is being called and hence the `constructor` is called everytime instead of `componentWillReceiveProps`

I hope you, I was able to explain

Comment: i know the different of constructor and componentWillReceiveProps, and i know how to use them, thanks.  </br> i want to ask in which cases the react will do component's constructor, in which case the react will do component's componentWillReceiveProps.

Comment: @ruroru, As I said in my answer, when the component is mounting it invokes the contructor and generally when the props change, it invokes the componentWillReceiveProps and as expalained in the answer why is your constructor getting called again and again

Comment: sorry,  i\`m busy recently, long time no login stackoverflow, so, 1.React document\`s constructor description; 2.using a map function are again and again mounting the same component whenever the renderGroups function is being called;         expect two case will run react constructor, anything else?

Comment: Those things are all I can think of now. If the answer helped, could you accept it

Comment: thank you, but it`s not my question want, heihei, but i`m very thank u to give me u think